# SQLite3 code to Dynamically insert Column Value of row data to delete

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite, sql-insert

i use python+SQLite to code. I have been trying to create a block where a user can enter a column value to delete corresponding row data in an SQLite3 database.

Practically, the code snippet below works, but i will have to enter all email addresses manually. I want to dynamically insert the email for this SQLite Line of code so as to delete corresponding records

```
DELETE FROM Records WHERE email = 'xyz@xyz.com'
```

I have tried the following;

```
entered_email = input('enter email: ')
string = f" 'DELETE FROM Records WHERE email = '{entered_email}'"
c.execute(string)
```

It does not work. I get the error line below

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "'DELETE FROM Records WHERE email = '": syntax error
```

I will be very glad if i can get an explanation or description on how best to go about this. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't concatenate user input in the query string - this opnns up your code to SQL injection.

Instead, use a parameterized query:

```
entered_email = input('enter email: ')
c.execute('DELETE FROM Records WHERE email =  ?', (entered_email, ))
```

Comment: Tried this earlier... I got an error 'sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are n supplied. n representing string lenght of any email entered

Comment: Thanks. Worked fine